# PDO FETCH OBJ Return False

Tags: php, pdo

I did a update of my php server version and now one of my PDO query doesn't work anymore (it was working for more than a year).
It return Boolean false.
I'm connected to a MSSQL server.
My connection is correct because all other queries work fine.
My SQL query work fine into MS-SQL management studio console.

Here my query:

```
<? 
  $db = new UseDB(UseDB::MyDB);

  $SQL = "DECLARE @vWL_NUMBER varchar(10);
        exec @vWL_NUMBER = uspGetNextControlCode 'WL_NUMBER';
        select @vWL_NUMBER  as WL_NUMBER ";   
        $q = $db->query($SQL);

        $row = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);            
        $WL_NUM=$row->WL_NUMBER;

?>
```

Comment: What is the real error as logged in your `sys.messages` table

Comment: I got no errors. it's like everything works bu didn't return anyresult.